# What does 'struck' mean in the context?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

What does 'struck' mean in the context? Does it mean 'to be impressed' or 'to come into somebody's mind suddenly', or else?

> Over the centuries various writers and thinkers, looking at humans
> from an outside perspective, have been ***struck*** by the theatrical
> quality of social life. The most famous quote expressing this comes
> from Shakespeare: “All the world’s a stage, / And all the men and
> women merely players; / They have their exits and their entrances, /
> And one man in his time plays many parts.” If the theater and actors
> were traditionally represented by the image of masks, writers such as
> Shakespeare are implying that all of us are constantly wearing masks.
> Some people are better actors than others. Evil types such as Iago in
> the play *Othello* are able to conceal their hostile intentions behind a
> friendly smile. Others are able to act with more confidence and
> bravado—they often become leaders. People with excellent acting skills
> can better navigate our complex social environments and get ahead.

[The Laws of Human Nature](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=0U5XDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT142&lpg=PT142&dq=Over%20the%20centuries%20various%20writers%20and%20thinkers,%20looking%20at%20humans%20from%20an%20outside%20perspective,%20have%20been%20struck%20by%20the%20theatrical%20quality%20of%20social%20life.&source=bl&ots=8EtAWs8lq3&sig=ACfU3U3JvinY7z6R8ien6faqrS9_SMD_hg&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwinjK7InsrwAhWDw4sBHfJPDMQQ6AEwAnoECAEQAw#v=onepage&q=Over%20the%20centuries%20various%20writers%20and%20thinkers%2C%20looking%20at%20humans%20from%20an%20outside%20perspective%2C%20have%20been%20struck%20by%20the%20theatrical%20quality%20of%20social%20life.&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

It means they noticed it; it was an important observation. The connotation of "struck" is that the observation was unavoidable because it reflects something real.